# Ask Ubuntu logo download link

Tags: discussion

From which website can I download the Ask Ubuntu logo?

I found this website which contains logos of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange: https://stackoverflow.design/brand/logo/, but there is no Ask Ubuntu logo in there. :(

---

This question does not answer my question: [Where can I get the Ask Ubuntu speech bubble logo?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2630)

It is about the speech bubble and does not include the entire logo.

I want an official website of Stack Exchange from where I can download the logo of Ask Ubuntu (similar to the one mentioned above), not a logo made by community members using their own photo editing skills.

---

My question has nothing to do with copyright stuff related to Ask Ubuntu logo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I get the Ask Ubuntu speech bubble logo?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2630/where-can-i-get-the-ask-ubuntu-speech-bubble-logo) Also here is a couple more sites I found https://mathiasbynens.github.io/stack-exchange-logos/

Comment: Why don't you download it from here? Just right click on the logo and select "save as".

Comment: @terdon because, depending on OP's goals, having a copy of the logo saved on their computer might be pretty worthless. For any meaningful usage of the logo, one needs to know their permissions: as in, what they are allowed to use the logo for, with what conditions. An official site with a download link tends to offer the essential information on licensing / permissions.

Comment: @Levente OK, but that isn't what the question is asking at all. All it says is "what page can I download from?" and the answer is "this one". If Random Person wants to ask about copyright issues then that should be made clear in the question. I don't see much point in us guessing.

Comment: @MarkKirby The linked question does not answer my question. I have edited my question and added details. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @terdon I tried that. I didn't work. I just got a blank .svg file. Anyway, check my updated question.

Comment: @Levente Please check the updated question.

Comment: That's odd. I just tried it (chromium on Arch Linux, right click on the logo and select "save image as") and I got a perfectly valid and working svg file. Also, you can right click and select "copy image address" which will give you this: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/Img/logo.svg?v=a83024ffc000 so you can even do `wget https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/Img/logo.svg` and get the file.

Comment: @terdon https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUsm5.png

Comment: @RandomPerson are you sure it is blank? Remember that the logo is white text, are you maybe looking at it with a white background?

Comment: @RandomPerson yes, exactly: that's white on white. Just download it and open it in an actual image editor that supports transparency and you will see it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can download it from *this* website. Either right click on the logo and select "save image as" or right click on the logo and select "copy image address" which will give you this: `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/Img/logo.svg?v=a83024ffc000` so you can even do:

```
 wget https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/Img/logo.svg
```

and get the file.

I just tried this and both approaches work. I even ran this:

```
inkscape -w 144 -h 48 logo.svg -o logo.png
```

Which created a png I can add to this very answer:

[image: Ask Ubuntu logo white text on white background, looks empty]

That *looks* like a blank image but that's because the logo's font is white and the image is being shown on a white background. In fact, when I posted my answer just now which briefly makes it flash with a different color background, I could see the image. I can also see it if I delete this answer which will also change the background:

[image: Screenshot of this answer deleted so the logo can be seen]

So, I also ran this to get a black background and, voilà:

[image: Ask Ubuntu logo with a black backround]

Comment: I use Windows. So `wget` won't work :(

Comment: @RandomPerson then don't use wget. Just do what I told you to do from the very beginning: ***right click and save image as***! The reason you think it does not work is because the logo is white text and you are opening it in a tool that puts it on a white background. Use a proper image viewer that can handle svg files and transparency and you will see that it isn't blank but instead is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I installed PhotoQt and I was able to see the logo. But, the logo's quality is not nice. It is nowhere equivalent to logos downloaded from https://stackoverflow.design/brand/logo/.

Comment: @RandomPerson svg files don't have "quality": they're a vector format. You are probably using some windows tool and converting to png. But all of this is very much off topic. The logo you get from this site is exactly what you were asking for. If you now need help on how to use this on Windows using Windows tools, please ask a question on [su].